# Animate UIView setFrame to force drawRect on each animatable frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, calayer

I've got a UIView with a UILabel on top. I have the UILabel's content mode set to 'UIContentModeLeft'. As expected, when I animate the frame of the UIView to be smaller than the original size, the label 'jumps' to the final frame without animating nicely.

As far as I can see, UIContentModeRedraw does not force 'drawRect' to be called on every 'animated frame'. I've tried using a custom CALayer as well but can't seem to cause the frame to resize smoothly.

Is there any way to do this? The animation as it stands is extremely glitchy. UIContentModes are not useful and I can't use a frame for contentStretch as well as none of the edges of the label can be stretched. What I really need is a 'refresh' of the label every time the parent view resizes.

Comment: Just a thought of the top of my head, have you looked into the key-frame animation methods? You probably get better granularity and control.

Comment: No that's essentially the same thing - as it internally uses a presentationLayer to do the actual animation and UIViewContentMode remains in effect. The only seems to be a NSTimer based animation (so that I explicitly call setFrame on each interval fired) but that's laggy and ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of doing this unfortunately, so I've learnt. The only other way is to actually run a timer that updates the frame every time it's invoked. This results in a very jerky animation given a resize of a complex view is time consuming. I ended up achieving the same thing with some pre-rendered onscreen elements and a whole lotta 'magical effects' behind the scene.